# Call a script along with parameters from if statement using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I have no control over and is on another domain.  The default procedure is to just include it in a script tag and it runs fine.

I don't want to run it by default so I have an if statement and if true I want to run the script.
So default option is:

```
<script src="http://domain/site/script?Id=12345&delayMs=2000&stayMs=10000&chance=0.1" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

I taught I could just use jQuery.getScript() to get it to run the above url but this does not work.  I do not know the correct link to the actual script and functions contained so I cannot getScript and call functions.

Any ideas would help.

Regards
Brian

Comment: What's the problem with `getScript()`?

Comment: Hi Johan,  I tried your suggestion below and using getScript() but it doesn't appear to do anything.  Let me explain, if I put the link in a script tag on the page as normal when the page loads it creates a floating div on the page with contents of the ID I pass to it.  When I call the script using ajax/getScript the div does not appear.

Comment: Try my update. Also, what serverside language are you using?

Comment: Ok tried that but this time I get an error on the page. Webpage error details User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3) Timestamp: Thu, 31 Oct 2013 13:37:33 UTC Message: Syntax error Line: 3 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: http://xxx/xxx/script?Id=12345&delayMs=2000&stayMs=10000&chance=0.0
I am trying to add this to a Microsoft SharePoint site page.

Comment: Ok finally got it!  When I put the url in a variable like you did in for the loadscript function below and then referenced it from the getScript() the script worked.  Thanks a mil for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're having cross domain issues, try this (`$.getScript()` is just a shorthand for this anyway, with the exception of `crossDomain: true`).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain/site/script?Id=12345&delayMs=2000&
                                    stayMs=10000&chance=0.1',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function () {
        // script is loaded
    },
    error: function () {
        // handle errors
    }
});
```

Another solution you can try using pure JS:

```
function loadScript(src, callback)
{
  var s,
      r,
      t;
  r = false;
  s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = src;
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //console.log( this.readyState ); 
    //uncomment this line to see which ready states are called.
    if ( !r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete') )
    {
      r = true;
      callback();
    }
  };
  t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  t.parent.insertBefore(s, t);
}
```

Usage:

```
var url = 'http://domain/site/script?Id=12345&delayMs=2000&
                                    stayMs=10000&chance=0.1';
loadScript(url, function(){
    console.log('script loaded');
});
```

Comment: This is the wrong way round.  `getScript` *will* work cross domain, but the ajax call won't.

Comment: @Archer `getScript` is just a normal `$.ajax` request, so please elaborate.

Comment: I've just tried it in the console with a script on one of my servers and `$.getScript` works but `$.ajax` complained about a cross domain call.  With `$.getScript` I was able to load the script and it ran fine, as I then had access to global variables and methods within that script.

Comment: @Archer Ok, sound wierd. According to the API they should be eqvivalent.

Comment: I agree, which is why I tested it.  At first I thought `$.getScript` would fail across domains, and commented on the question, but then after testing I deleted it.  I'm surprised by this as well.

Comment: @Archer Seems to be working cross domain for me, though: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Wme/

Comment: That's because the server is set up to allow cross-domain calls.  You can't rely on a CDN for this type of test.  Use a script on one of your own servers instead.

Comment: Okay - the difference is `dataType: 'script'`.  If you remove that it won't work.  I've learnt something new today - thanks :)